# Visualizing an isosurface generated with marching cubes

Tags: opengl, marching-cubes, vispy

I'm currently using OpenGL (more specifically through the VisPy bindings) to do some scientific data visualization. I have a volumetric dataset, and I would like to visualize some isosurfaces present inside of it. I generate the isosurfaces using the built-in marching cubes algorithm in Python's `skimage.measure` library.

So, I have the set of vertices, and I have the set of indices which define the triangulation of the mesh as output by `skimage.measure.marching_cubes`. These can be directly converted to `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` objects for rendering. But what is the proper way to apply a texture to the isosurface? I don't need to do anything fancy, basically just some color so it can be visualized more clearly.

Essentially, here is my point of confusion. Vertex coordinates are defined on the box `[0,2] x [0,2] x [0, 1]`, because my volume is twice as long in `x` and `y` as it is in `z`. Texture coordinates are always defined on the `[0,1] x [0,1] x [0, 1]` cube if my understanding is correct. I've been attempting to generate a simple volumetric texture, converting vertex coordinates to texture coordinates by dividing the `x` and `y` components by two, and then using those coordinates in the volumetric texture as the `texcoord`. But this doesn't work (please see attached image). Here's some code:

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_projection;
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_texcoord;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_model * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_texcoord  = a_texcoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler3D u_texture;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
void main() {
    float r = texture3D(u_texture, v_texcoord).r;
    float g = texture3D(u_texture, v_texcoord).g;
    float b = texture3D(u_texture, v_texcoord).b;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1);
}
```

The 3D texture is currently set to the following. Please note that this texture isn't supposed to mean all that much; I'm just trying to put a gradient in various directions and play around with the settings so I can see a difference in the output. Changing this texture has no effect on what I see.

```
D, H, W = 64, 128, 128
texture_arr = np.ones((W, H, D, 4)).astype(np.float32)
texture_arr[...] *= np.linspace(0, 1, W)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
texture_arr[...] *= np.linspace(0, 1, H)[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
texture_arr[...] *= np.linspace(0, 1, D)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
```

The `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` are exactly as output by the marching cubes algorithm. As described above, `texcoord` is simply the vertex coordinate with `x` and `y` coordinates divided by two.

Here's a screenshot of what I see, which has the correct isosurface shape but is textured horribly wrong.

[image: A horribly textured isosurface.]

Answer (score 0):

gl_FragColor was deprecated since OpenGL 3.0, are you using an older or newer version of OpenGL?  Maybe you can try this fragment shader.

```
uniform sampler3D u_texture;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
out vec4 FragColor;    
void main() 
{
    FragColor = vec4(texture(u_texture, v_texcoord), 1);
}
```